# how to use $resource to get the data from local json file

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I am trying multiple ways to access my users in a local json file in able to later compare them to the users input. and if there is a match, access is allowed, but my main problem now is just getting to those users.
  My code so far:

[entire code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oja5W.png)

[json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRUbw.png)

What am i doing wrong? i am such a newbie in programming. I have been trying different things and nothing works.
Thanks so much for help

Comment: Whats means local? Are you have local http server?

Comment: @AlexanderAnikeev.. local json file with all my users i mean and to run my angular app im using http-server.

Answer (score 3):

Can you access the file through the browser (via your url localhost:8080/resources/data/users.json)?

If you can't, you will not be able to get access through the $resource or $http.

If you can, any method should work:

1) Via [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

```
$scope.users = [];

var UsersResource = $resource('/resources/data/users.json');
```

where we can get response by callback

```
UsersResource.get({}, function(response) {
    $scope.users = response;
});
```

or by $promise

```
UsersResource.get().$promise.then(function(response) {
    $scope.users = response;
});
```

2) Via [$http.get](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get)

```
$scope.users = [];

$http.get('/resources/data/users.json').then(function(response) {
    $scope.users = response;
});
```

In your sample, your are trying to get array of users by returning $resource, but $resource returns a object with methods. Each method has callbacks (success, error) or return $promise object.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `$resource` if you are just going to fetch a json file. Use `$http` instead:

```
this.getUsers = function(){
  return $http.get('path/to/file.json');
};
```

And usage:

```
dataService.getUsers().then(function(resp){
    //Do something with the data
    $scope.users = resp;
})
```

`$resource` is meant to be used when communicating with RESTful apis. What your `getUsers()` is doing is actually returning a resource-object, upon which you can then call `get()`. But I recommend using `$http` in this case.

Comment: Thank You, i tried this way and still not working,,  i am getting a 404 error:
angular.js:11881 GET http://localhost:8080/resources/data/users.json 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I dont know how your development environment looks, but if you precompile the code with a module bundler you will need to copy the json file to the `build` directory or similar. The code works its just the path to the file that is wrong!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use $resouce then you need to create two functions in your controller/factory where "templatesSuccess" return data of request.

```
        getAllTemplates: function(query) {
            return $resource(CONST.CONFIG.BASE_URL + 'receiver/get-templates').get(query, obj.templatesSuccess).$promise;
        },


        templatesSuccess: function(response) {
            obj.allTemplates = response;
        },
```

Comment: thank you for your help.. but i am not sure i fully understand the answer or the syntax. confused with this line: return $resource(CONST.CONFIG.BASE_URL + 'receiver/get-templates').get(query, obj.templatesSuccess).$promise;

Comment: This is complete path from where you want to fetch APIs... Here you can give complete json file path